# What does a major-7 chord resolve/lead to?

Tags: theory, chords

I reckon the major-7 chord is my favourite guitar chord.

I was strumming `Amaj7` chord and got a lovely first line to a song, but I am not musical enough to figure out what chords fit the melody I was singing. What would be some obvious chords to directly follow such a chord? And in normal (not jazz) music, which chords in a key would lend themselves well to being substituted with the major-7 alternative - i.e. is it more likely Amaj7 is Imaj7, Vmaj7, etc?

Comment: Damnit how do I get a chord fingering to appear? I did it by mistake the other day, now I can't get it to display a typical Amaj7 voicing.

Comment: Indent by four spaces (like a code block).

Comment: Is it documented what chord types it recognises and the namings one has to use?

Comment: In A major, Amaj7 would possibly resolve to Dmaj7 (Imaj7 to IVmaj7)

Comment: @Mr.Boy Documentation is here: http://jtab.tardate.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand how chords with 7ths work, you need to know the scale you are using. The chords most commonly used are built on thirds, so if you choose a scale and then a note from that scale, you'll see what chords are maj7 chords, by ascending thirds from the note you chose. *

In the major scale, only the I and IV are major chords *and* have a major 7th.

So, let's say you want to use the Amaj7 chord. One way to look at this chord would be to consider it the Imaj7 from the A major scale. The chord is built on thirds -- A,C#,E,G# (G# is a major 7th). **After the Amaj7 chord, you can use any chord from the scale**, like you would use if you simply had a A (without the maj7).

Pretty much the same would work if you considered it as a IVmaj7. It would be the IV from the E major scale. So, you can create a chord progression in the E major scale and instead of a simple A chord, to play a nice Amaj7.

<sub>What I like to do sometimes is to play the chord as it is, without the 7th and then add the 7th.</sub>

Also, I've never seen a Vmaj7 chord. The V usually is dominant (V7); that means it has a minor 7th instead of a major one; one semitone lower.

*The V doesn't have a major seventh. Let's assume we are in the A major scale. The notes in the A major scale are A,B,C#,D,E,F#,G#. The V chord has E as a root. Let's ascend thirds from E and see what kind of chord we have:

- E (root)
- G# (major third)
- B (perfect fifth); so far we have a major chord
- D (minor 7th).

So the V is a 7 chord, not a maj7 one.

Comment: "In the major scale, only the I and IV are major chords and have a major 7th." - I didn't understand that, could you reword or clarify in your answer? e.g. why doesn't V "have a major 7th"?

Comment: @Mr.Boy I added more info at the end of my answer

Comment: After your edits I think it all makes sense, especially why Vmaj7 isn't a thing :) So in summary, a maj7 can be directly substituted for the same degree plain major chord in that key?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Yup; Also, keep in mind that the 'maj' goes to the 7th, not the chord. Another similar chord is Aminmaj7 which is a Aminor chord with a major 7th (the I from the harmonic minor scale). It's a weird sounding chord; try it out.

Comment: And this makes sense... I could see Bm, C#m and D would fit nicely with Amaj7 and now I checked those are chords from the key of A mjor (not a key I know off-hand, but Amaj7 is the easiest maj7 chord I know on guitar!)

Comment: @Mr.Boy doesn't matter that you don't know they off-hand. If you can't figure them out at the moment, try writing down the notes from the A major scale, take each note as a root and ascend thirds. This way you'll be able to see what chords are in the A major scale.

Comment: Oh yeah, I can work out chords to any key but I meant I didn't recognise those chords as being in A. Whereas if I noticed Am, F and G were working against Cmaj7 I'd have thought "huh, those are all chords from C major" :)